# Prevent data transfer android when using app

Tags: android, security

I am trying to make something like preventing user uses my app when he in the data transfer state like in every payment apps. I already search for that even ask GPT but cannot find the exact answer. what I want is something like this
[image: payment app]

I assume that is built in SDK because I found several payment app show the same UI and the same wording, so I doubt if it's using kind of custom alert dialog that shows after detecting usb by custom code

[Update] I just realize that the apps that have the protection is included in the list of payment protection by the app [image]